# Not able to display items into a cart

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's probably a simple fix, m trying to help a friend with something and I’m not very experienced with web dev. I just need a way to display the items that have been added to cart. All of the items are showing up in the console log but never displayed on the actual web page.

```js
let cart = [];

function addToCart(item) {
  cart.push(item);
  console.log(item + " added to cart.");
}

function displayCart() {
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your cart is empty.");
  } else {
    console.log("Items in your cart:");
    cart.forEach(item => console.log(item));
  }
}

function removeFromCart(item) {
  let index = cart.indexOf(item);
  if (index === -1) {
    console.log(item + " not found in cart.");
  } else {
    cart.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(item + " removed from cart.");
  }
}
addToCart("item");
displayCart();
removeFromCart("item");
displayCart();
```

```html
<h2>Graphics Cards</h2>
<ol>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti - €1,199 <button onclick="addToCart('NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Ti')">Add to
        Cart</button></li>
  <li>AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT - €999 <button onclick="addToCart('AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT')">Add to Cart</button></li>
</ol>

<h1> Items Currently In Your Cart</h1>
<ul id="cart-items">
  <!-- Items will be added here automatically -->
</ul>
<script src="script.js">
  function addToCart(item) {
    cart.push(item);
    // Display items in the cart
    displayCart();
    updateCartDisplay();
  }

  function updateCartDisplay() {
    let cartList = document.getElementById('cart-items');
    cartList.innerHTML = '';
    // Add items to the cart list
    cart.forEach(item => {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
      cartList.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not erase a question and replace it with `{answered questions now}`

Comment: Why not? i didn't make the question and someone else was logged into my account so I don’t want it visible on my profile.

Comment: `<script src="script.js">
  function addToCart(item) {` using src and adding content directly seems odd/wrong here.

Comment: @AndrewHogan If that's true then flag your question for moderator attention and give them the full explanation

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a text node, just set `innerText` on the list item.

Also, you had a function that did nothing but log to the console, and you had a function in two places. I've removed a bunch of code and just left what's needed and the unused remove function. If you want to log to the console, do it in the functions here instead of separate ones.

A few other suggestions:

- Track products by ID, not title. Titles can change and tend to contain special characters that make coding with them problematic. Use an array of objects with ID and name properties. Later you can easily add price, etc.
- Go completely data-driven. Build your item list dynamically, too, from a data array.
- Deduplicate by checking for ID in the `cart` array before pushing to it.

```js
let cart = [];
const cartList = document.getElementById('cart-items');

function addToCart(item) {
  cart.push(item);
  updateCartDisplay();
}

function removeFromCart(idx) {
  const removedItem = cart[idx];
  cart.splice(idx, 1);
  updateCartDisplay();
  console.log(removedItem + " removed from cart.");
}

function updateCartDisplay() {
  cartList.innerHTML = '';

  // Add items to the cart list
  cart.forEach((item, i) => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = item + ' ';
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerText = 'Remove';
    btn.onclick = index => removeFromCart(i);
    li.append(btn);

    cartList.append(li);
  });
}
```

```html
<h2>Graphics Cards</h2>

<ol>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti - €1,199 <button onclick="addToCart('NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Ti')">Add to Cart</button></li>
  <li>AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT - €999 <button onclick="addToCart('AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT')">Add to Cart</button></li>
</ol>

<h1> Items Currently In Your Cart</h1>

<ul id="cart-items">
  <!-- Items will be added here automatically -->
</ul>
```